# Answering questions with outside sources

Tags: discussion

Some of my answers come quickly after a question pops up, because I can Google the answer quickly and there are numerous sources out there having addressed the question.

Sometimes I feel bad getting rep from something that is essentially an edited copy-paste (I do always cite the site I recite from). Sure, I cleaned up whatever I've found on-line, but it's not really *my words*.

I receive personal benefit from answering these questions, as they expand my knowledge of the Bible, and I feel that usually the answers are good answers to the questions, but again, I'm pulling off someone else's words. What should I do in these cases? Sometimes another answer pops up about the same time, saying a different thing, citing a different site or clearly sourced from memory. *Should I make these answers Community Wiki?*

Comment: "I do always cite the site I recite from" and would a wood chuck chuck wood, and a tooter tutored two tooters to toot, and so on.

Comment: related: [What should we do about answers that include significant portions of other answers?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1561) and [Answers copied from an external source](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/154)

Comment: :) at first, I was unintentiaonally rhyming, and then I figured I could make the sentence rhyme more

Comment: @fredsbend - yes, but I'm more concerned about the issue of including significant content sourced from other sites on the internet?

Comment: @fredsbend - thanks, that helps. So, as long as I source it **and** put it my own words it so it's not a straight copy-paste, that would be ok?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That great theologian, Tom Lehrer, perhaps put it best:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IL4vWJbwmqM

> I am never forget the day I first meet the great Lobachevsky.
>
> In one word he told me secret of success in mathematics:
> Plagiarize!
>
> Plagiarize,
> Let no one else's work evade your eyes,
> Remember why the good Lord made your eyes,
> So don't shade your eyes,
> But plagiarize, plagiarize, plagiarize -
> Only be sure always to call it please 'research'.

Now, obviously plagarism isn't what we want, but the joke makes the point - good research may often look like plagarism.  Indeed "novelty" in theology is a bad word.  Ideally, you don't say anything "new."

I believe it was Charles Spurgeon who said, "Hopefully I said nothing new - I only arranged the words differently."

Obviously, you should "arrange" from multiple sources, but your rephrasing of others' research is what good theology is often about - putting together old ideas in a clear, compelling, and cohesive manner that addresses the concern of the questioner.

It works!